# Proof of Banach's homeomorphism theorem without the contraction map principle.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, reference-request, fixed-point-theorems

Let $E$ a Banach's space and $X\subset E$ open. The Banach's homeomorphism theorem tells us that if a function $F:X\to E$ is a contraction on $X$ then  $(I+F):X\to E$ is a homeomorphism of $X$ onto the open subset $(I+F)(X)$ of $E$, where $I$ denotes the identity map on $E$.

The proof most commonly of the Banach's homeomorphism theorem seen in textbooks of relies on the Banach fixed-point theorem.

I ask, is there any proof of Banach's theorem homeomorphism that do not use the contraction map principle? Some reference?

I have thought of a proof in spaces of finite demension. But in the midst of my attempts to end the proof, I end up arriving in places where the only output I see to complete the proof is to apply some equivalent idea to contractiom map principle or the domain invariance theorem. And I want to avoid these two results.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to avoid those results?

Comment: @UmbertoP. 
Yes. There is. But speaking in terms of mathematics fundamentals I do not believe that such a test would find walking through results that were independent of Banach's fixed point theorem or domain invariance theorem. I think I could proof that uses connectness. I am writing a review about the implicit function theorem. Indeed an alternative proof that does not use the Banach's fixed point theorem.